# laravel dusk chrome browser unable to lunch

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-5.8, laravel-dusk

my chrome is not started for dusktesting. error i got

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Ch

rome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

My DuskTestCase.php

```
protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
         //   '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
                $options
            )
        );
    }
```

Is there anyway to fix this? any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Exact same issue here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: my problem was solved after restarting my computer